# how to insert data into database at joomla article

Tags: joomla1.7

I am beginner in joomla development. I know PHP, MySql. But I want to   insert data into database (phpmyadmin) in joomla. how to do it in a joomla article. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run insert query in joomla in  this way.

```
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "INSERT INTO '#__example_table' ('name','email','username')
            VALUES ('John Smith','johnsmith@domain.example','johnsmith')";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of insert query.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
```

Get column names to a variable as array.

```
$columns = array('fieldname1','fieldname2');
$values = array(1,$db->quote('my value'),$db->quote('my message');
```

Insert query

```
$query->insert($db->quoteName('#__tablename'))
      ->columns($db->quoteName($columns)
      ->values(implode(',',$values));
```

Set the query

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```